# how does one check if a letter is used after input?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am supposed to write a program that asks the user to enter a word with 5 letters and then check whether the third letter is e or not.

```
input('Enter word with 5 letters:'
if [2] == e:
    print("the third letter is e")
```

but nothing happens after I input a word with 5 letters.

[image]

Comment: This is not even valid code.

Comment: Just quick question to hopefully illustrate something you don't seem to have addressed -- how do you know the word is five letters or not?

Answer (score 1):

Corrected code should be like this:

```
word = input('Enter word with 5 letters: ')
if word[2] == 'e':
    print("the third letter is e")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
user_input = input('Enter word with 5 letters:')
if user_input[2] == 'e':
    print("the third letter is e")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the value, in this case the input, into a variable and then access its letters with [].

```
userInput = input('Enter word with 5 letters: ')
if userInput[2] == 'e':
    print("the third letter is e")
```

You always have to save values, information and actions into variables if you want to use or modify them further on.

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can read strings like arrays.
For example:

```
myString = "abcdef"
print(myString[3])
```

Your result will be `d`
So what you have to do is
1st take the input and save it to a variable like this

```
string_input = input()
```

2nd check if the third letter is 'e' or not

```
if(string_input[2]=='e'):
    print("Third letter is e")
```

Note: string[] returns char value